# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, voice

I am trying to run a voice program in Python 3.7.4 and with pyttsx library. But I've faced up with lots of problems while converting the file into an .exe file from .py file. Initially the program as executed in python runs fine. But when i converted the .py file to.exe using pyinstaller it gives me the following error while running :

````
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
  File "c:\users\s som\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DesktopAi.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'
[11180] Failed to execute script DesktopAi ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers DesktopAi.py
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.